How to enable code analysis IDE0058 as a build error?
I want to enable IDE0058 as an error during build. Here's how I attempted to do that.

Start Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.11.2)

Create new project. Project type: C#, Windows, Console -> Console App "A project for creating a command-line application that can run on .NET on WIndows, Linux and macOS"

Next

Project name: CodeAnalysisError

Location: somewhere on my hard disk

[x] Place solution and project in the same directory

Next

Framework: .NET 8.0 (Long Term Support)

Create

Content of Program.cs is taken from the example of IDE0058:
System.Convert.ToInt32("35");


Right click the project in solution explorer

Choose Add / New item ...

In the filter, type "editor"

Choose "editorconfig File (empty)


Add

The default content of the file is
# All files
[*]
indent_style = space

# Xml files
[*.xml]
indent_size = 2


Add the line in section [*]
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0058.severity = error


Build the project. It succeeds
Build started at 09:33...
1>------ Build started: Project: CodeAnalysisError, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>CodeAnalysisError -> C: \[redacted]\CodeAnalysisError\bin\Debug\net8.0\CodeAnalysisError.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 09:33 and took 10,612 seconds ==========



For reference, the .csproj file looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EditorConfigFiles Remove="C:\[redacted]\CodeAnalysisError\.editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="C:\[redacted]\CodeAnalysisError\.editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

The IDE displays the wiggly lines right from the start:

I have tried:

adding <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>, but that should not be necessary, since enable code analysis

is enabled by default for projects that target .NET 5 and later versions.


moving the rule to [*.cs] (which again, I think should not matter):
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0058.severity = error


Adding <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>, as mentioned here

Adding <AnalysisMode>All</AnalysisMode> as mentioned here just because I wanted to see if I could let the build fail in any way. This starts finding the warning CA1305, but not IDE0058.

Adding <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors> lets the build fail, due to CA1305. I removed that for a moment.

Setting <AnalysisLevel>preview-recommended</AnalysisLevel> as mentioned here found another warning:
1>CSC : warning EnableGenerateDocumentationFile: Set MSBuild property 'GenerateDocumentationFile' to 'true' in project file to enable IDE0005 (Remove unnecessary usings/imports) on build (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/41640)


I read about .globalconfig here but figured that I should not need this.

I read about .editorconfig here to make sure I didn't miss something.

I made sure that "[x] Follow project coding conventions" is turned as as mentioned here

I tried using a .ruleset file, but VS tells me that they are deprecated in favor of .editorconfig.

Upgrading Visual Studio from 17.10.x to 17.11.2


In summary, I have done everything which is also mentioned in other questions

my files look like this accepted solution
considering this answer, removing the two `s did not help.

So, how do I get a build error for IDE0058? If you answer, please describe the steps in detail, so I can follow. I spent more than 2.5 hours already. My code, my solution and everything is minimal.

If you move this line into a method, IDE0058 will be reported, so I guess top-level statement is ignored by this analysis.

@shingo: Indeed. Moving my code into a Program class and a Main() method makes it appear. What the ...

@ThomasWeller This smells like a bug in this specific analyzer. Try reporting it on their github - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers

@Malt: added bug 7408

It's not only about top-level statements. I tried the 18 steps with a full Program class from the beginning and it doesn't work either.

@ThomasWeller, is there new update in your issue? I have shared more steps on how dis this.

If you write the following code to a function(e.g:Test),  VS will treat the code analysis IDE0058 as a build error.
System.Convert.ToInt32("35");

void Test()
{
    System.Convert.ToInt32("35");
}


Test result:

Error List

Build Failed:

Update
1.csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
     <AnalysisLevel>preview-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EditorConfigFiles Remove="C:\Users\source\repos\CodeAnalysisError\CodeAnalysisError\.editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="C:\Users\source\repos\CodeAnalysisError\CodeAnalysisError\.editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


2.editorconfig
# C# files
[*.cs]

# Indentation and spacing
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
tab_width = 4

#### Diagnostic configuration ####

dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0058.severity = error

Test result:


Sorry, but no, it doesn't: https://i.sstatic.net/0kycrdUC.png Please be more specific on how you did this.

(And I neither want to put my code into a method because of this, nor do I want to move my code out of classes.)

You don't need move your code out of classes. More details updated.

You can not. The reason for this is that the Roslyn Code Analyzer responsible for this is not available during the build, but only within the environment of your IDE.
It might turn out that SA1409 will give similar results, and that one can configured to run without your IDE being present.
